# How to post the post with template using Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Is it possible to post on user's timeline the post with custom template? 
I have an facebook app, and want to post on user's timeline the post like this, or another custom html-template.

The idea is to share link with custom template or create post which links to my webpage.

For example like this

[image]

*If you click on map area you will be redirected to *Endomodo Sports web page*

Maybe it predefined by Facebook templates which depends on [Open Graph actions and objects](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph)?

Comment: There is no way to post with custom templates. There are a few templates defined by Facebook that can be used

Comment: @WizKid so, how can I publish the same post as on screenshot?

Comment: Yes. Use Open Graph actions

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I should use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/fitness.bikes/

Comment: If you want to post biking then yes